# How to get file list from ftp order by modified date

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

How to get file list from ftp order by modified date?, i have a code bellow but its coming order by name in asc

```
$this->load->library('ftp');
$config['hostname'] = "hostname";
$config['username'] = "username";
$config['password'] = "password";
$config['debug'] = FALSE;
$config['timeout'] = 10;

$conn = $this->ftp->connect($config);
if(FALSE !=$conn){
    $files = $this->ftp->list_files('/');
}
```

Comment: Did you refer a `CI user guide`?

Comment: Yes i refered but i did not get there

Comment: Question, are you getting the date modified value? or anything you can parse on the array `$files`?

Comment: i'm getting only file name in an array